# Color coding cells in a table based on the cell value using Jinja templates

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I have a simple flask app and need to display a table of values, with the cell backgrounds colour coded based on the cell value according to thresholds. I'm generating the table content as follows:

```
  {% block dashboard_table2 %}
      <table>
      {% for row in data %}
          {% for item in row %}
              <td>{{ item }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </table>
  {% endblock %}
```

I tried wrapping the values in style tags like this in Python but it didn't work:

```
  if int(value) <= 10:
      value = '<p style="background-color:Red">' + value + '</p>'
```

I'm guessing the CSS for the page is overriding the style attribute. I also tried just setting the text color attribute instead of background-color but no dice. Any suggestions on a good way to do this? I'd like to have a concise way to specify threshold values that aren't hard-coded in the templates.

Comment: Don't "guess". Are those style tags being output in the HTML at all (use View Source)? If not, something is wrong with the way you're calling it - how is `value` related to anything?

Comment: Fixed a mistake in the example. value is the text to appear in the table cell. The styling wasn't making it into the HTML, it is now but it just appearing as part of the cell text contents.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put this display logic in your template:

```
<table>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
            {% if item <= 10 %}
                <td class="under-limit">{{ item }}</td>
            {% else %}
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Then, in your CSS you can use:

```
.under-limit { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
   {% for row in row %}
       {% if item <= 10 %}
       <tr style ="background-color: red">
           <td> {{ item }} </td>
       </tr>
       {% else %}
       <tr>
           <td> {{ item }} </td>
       </tr>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This works for me.