# Color coding cells in a table based on the cell value using Jinja2

Tags: css, flask, jinja2

To expand upon this excellent question: [Color coding cells in a table based on the cell value using Jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239962/color-coding-cells-in-a-table-based-on-the-cell-value-using-jinja-templates)

How could we apply this to only a certain column of a table? ie. the second column for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over items in a row (i.e. columns for a row), you can use `loop.index0` or `loop.index` to style the desired column.

So for example, if you put `{% if loop.index == 2 %} <td class="special-colour"> {{ item }} </td>{% endif %}` inside your `{% for item in row %}` loop, the `.special-colour` class  will only apply to the second item.