# Loop through rows, data instead of just printing table in Jinja template

Tags: python, html, flask, gunicorn

Right now my Jinja code shows a simple table statement that works well enough:

```
{% for table in tables %}
{{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

And it is called from my Flask app with this code:

```
return render_template('results.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')])
```

If I wanted to print the same table per row and item instead of {% for table in tables %} how would that look in the Jinja template?  My goal is to eventually modify table background cells based on value similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239962/color-coding-cells-in-a-table-based-on-the-cell-value-using-jinja-templates).  When I try to mimic the code in that post my table doesn't render properly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you can use `iterrows`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}])
```

```py
{% for index, row in df.iterrows() %}
{{ row['value']|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, reading up more on iterrows I found this page which gave me the winning block in my Jinja template: http://www.marknagelberg.com/creating-pdf-reports-with-python-pdfkit-and-jinja2-templates/

Comment: That’s a good find. I’ve used that same post when I wrote my resume with that same toolset.